# Convert open cv haar features xml files to images

Tags: xml, image, opencv

I would like to know if there is a way to go from the xml files of the haar cascades (they come with OpenCV, or can be found [here](http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34/)) to images, such as [those](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ippi/ippi_ch14/Images/fig14-13_large.jpg)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found description of what is inside the xml file [here for the rectangles](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/63898) and [here for the left and right values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978742/what-do-the-left-and-right-values-mean-in-the-haar-cascade-xml-files).